# :after pseudo not taking direction (rtl) in consideration? (Firefox)

Tags: css, firefox, right-to-left

I have this css to put an icon after each external link:

```
a[target="_blank"]:after {
    background: url("images/external_icon.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    border: 0 none;
    content: "";
    padding: 0 14px 0 0;
}
```

If I would to change to `:before` instead, the icon will appear in front of the link instead. So far, so good.

But in my right-to-left version of the site, while using `direction: rtl;`, the icon still appears to the right of the element, instead of being "flipped" to the other side. Changing to a `:before` will still make the icon appear to the right of the element.

Is this a known FF bug? Is there any other solution?
(Works fine in Chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution. Make it inline-block instead.

```
display: inline-block;
height: 13px;
width: 13px;
```

Simple solution, but getting there isn't aslways as easy.

I still feel like the css from the question might be a browser bug?

Comment: You could look in their Bugzilla (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) to se if you can find anything about the bug. If you don't find it, you should file it. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox behavior seems to be correct: the rendering of the `:after` should be the same as the rendering of an empty span with those styles inserted at the end of the `a[target="_blank"]`.  If you try that, you get identical behavior in Chrome and Firefox, and it matches the Firefox behavior for `:after`.

You may want to file a WebKit bug, though.